# Check response of git push from shell script

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

I'm trying to detect from bash if my `git push` was successful. I am checking for local changes previously in my script like this:

```
if [ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
```

and that works fine. This is the expression I have tried but this one doesn't work, in fact it errors:

```
if [ "$(git push --porcelain)" -eq "Done" ]; then
```

yields:

```
Done: integer expression expected
```

When I run `git push --porcelain` from the command line, the output is `Done`. Does this mean I should be checking for that text in my condition?

If I do the previous comparison, that doesn't work either, I get the same error:

```
1 file changed, 309 insertions(+)
Current branch master is up to date.
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 3.59 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
bash: [: To https://github.com/blah...
        refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master     88aff43..cf0c97c
Done: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your condition check should have been something like:-

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(git push --porcelain)" == *"Done"* ]]
then
  echo "git push was successful!"
fi
```

`-eq` is for integer comparisons, `==` is for string comparisons. The following illustrates the difference.

```
[[ 00 -eq 0 ]] && echo "zero is zero, regardless of its representation"
[[ 00 = 0 ]] || echo "00 and 0 are two different strings"
```

Comment: Thanks, just the job!

Answer (score 15):

`git push` returns a zero exit code on success, and non-zero on failure.

So you can write:

```
if git push
then
  echo "git push succeeded"
else
  echo "git push failed"
fi
```